# grep from screen output and detach

Tags: bash, shell

I'm currently writing a bash script which periodically checks for some special words in the server output of a detached screen session, but it enters the session (if grep found something) instead of showing the grepped output. Here is what I've tried:

```
screen -r foo | grep bar
```

This gives me the correct return code, but doesn't detach the session afterwards! I also tried `&& screen -d` but that changes nothing.
So how can my script tell me if "bar" is in the output of the server running in my "foo" screen session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem, I think, is that `screen` doesn't output in a way that can be searched by `grep`. If it did, then your attempt at `screen -r foo | grep bar && screen -d` would likely have been the right way to go about it.

I'd suggest starting the initial `screen` session with the `-L` option to enable logging. Then you can search the log file for the value you want.